# what command replaces an expression with a matched down value?

Tags: core-language

Suppose a composite expression matches a replacement pattern in the down values of the expression head.  How exactly does Mma replace the expression using the matched rule?  Can we write down an expression equivalent to the one used for evaluation?  Where is this documented?

For example, if `f[x_]:=x^2` and I want `f[2]`, I can see that I could do something equivalent *after* clearing `f` as say `Replace[f[2], {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2}]`.  But what is the correct expression without clearing the function definition?

Comment: `Replace[Unevaluated@f[2], {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2}]`? Though I don't claim it is what is described in evaluation tutorial as 'applying rules'.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks.  I thought I had tried that, but it works.  How can I determine if this is what "applying the rules" means?